How to Declare RpcBaseOptions?
I have two calls to fetchAllDigitalAssetWithTokenByOwnerAndMint
Call 1 (this works):
const a_asset = await fetchAllDigitalAssetWithTokenByOwnerAndMint(umi, aWallet.publicKey, mint.publicKey, 
    {commitment: 'processed'})

Call 2 (does not work)
const opts = {commitment: 'processed'}
const p_asset = await fetchAllDigitalAssetWithTokenByOwnerAndMint(umi, pWallet.publicKey, mint.publicKey, opts)

Call 2 gives me an error:
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
003 pre_recovery.ts(53,114): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ commitment: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RpcBaseOptions'.
  Types of property 'commitment' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Commitment | undefined'.

I'd like to have a variable for the RpcBaseOptions so that if I make changes it applies to all the calls.  I can not  import RpcBaseOptions and make an RpcBaseOptions per
import {RpcBaseOptions} from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

gives
error TS2305: Module '"@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata"' has no exported member 'RpcBaseOptions'.

How should I handle this?  My googling and the doc's don't have any examples.  Thank you! :)

import { Commitment } from '@solana/web3.js';
interface RpcBaseOptions {
commitment?: Commitment;
}
const opts: RpcBaseOptions = { commitment: 'processed' };
const p_asset = await fetchAllDigitalAssetWithTokenByOwnerAndMint(
umi,
pWallet.publicKey,
mint.publicKey,
opts
);
Then instead of a generic string, ensure that commitment is one of the allowed literals:
const opts: RpcBaseOptions = { commitment: 'processed' as Commitment };
Ensure that the commitment type matches the expected Commitment type.
You can check this repository for example(s) => https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js
